# create list without findall in prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

I'm working on a predicate to generate a list of values from rules.
I have these rules:

```
casilla(1,4,1,1,3).
casilla(1,4,1,2,1).
casilla(1,4,1,3,2).
casilla(1,4,1,4,4).
casilla(1,4,2,1,0).
casilla(1,4,2,2,4).
casilla(1,4,2,3,0).
casilla(1,4,2,4,0).
casilla(1,4,3,1,1).
casilla(1,4,3,2,0).
casilla(1,4,3,3,0).
casilla(1,4,3,4,2).
casilla(1,4,4,1,4).
casilla(1,4,4,2,2).
casilla(1,4,4,3,3).
casilla(1,4,4,4,1).
```

and I need to save the last value of each rule in a list, for example:

```
BOARD = [3, 1, 2, 4, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1].
```

I try to recursively save every element of this form:

```
createBoard2(N, M, Difficulty, [VALUE]) :-
   casilla(Difficulty,N,_,_,VALUE).
createBoard2(N, M, Difficulty, [VALUE,T]) :-
   casilla(Difficulty,N,_,_,X),
   createBoard2(N, M, Difficulty,T).
```

but really I do not understand the error,I only returns the first `VALUE` thanks.

Comment: `[VALUE,T]` should be `[VALUE|T]`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid findall/3 (why?), we need something like this inefficient, procedural code:

```
createBoard2(N, M, Difficulty, L) :- createBoard2(N, M, Difficulty, [], L).
createBoard2(N, M, Difficulty, Seen, [VALUE|R]) :-
   casilla(Difficulty,N,X,Y,VALUE),
   \+ memberchk(casilla(Difficulty,N,X,Y,VALUE), Seen),
   !, createBoard2(N, M, Difficulty, [casilla(Difficulty,N,X,Y,VALUE)|Seen], R).
createBoard2(_N, _M, _Difficulty, _Acc, []).
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use something like `findall/3`, then you should not store your data in the form of facts.

Alternative 1: put your `casilla/5` terms into a separate data file, then use `open/3` and `read/2` to read these terms one by one from this file into a list.

Alternative 2: put all the `casilla/5` terms into a single fact as a list, i.e.

```
casillas([
    casilla(1,4,1,1,3),
    casilla(1,4,1,2,1),
    ...
]).
```